# run multiple data sets through one jupyter notebook (ipython) file

Tags: python, database, input, jupyter-notebook

I have written some code that takes a data set, and performs quite some heavy calculations. I have written the code in such a way where only the name of the input data needs to be changed (`'WTW_decades/1980wtw.txt'` in the code below), and on the basis of that data file, all variables change such that it can run through the code. Tonight, I want all data to run through the same jupyter notebook file, without me having to reenter the name of each specific different dataset. My code looks the following:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt('WTW_decades/1980wtw.txt', dtype=[('a','|S5'),('b','|S5'),('amount','f8')], usemask=True)
print(data)

def create_edgelist_binary(): #creates a binary edgelist
    el = [] #name of the edge list
    for i in range(len(data)):
        el.append([data[i][0].decode('UTF-8'), data[i][1].decode('UTF-8')])
    return(el)

binary_edgelist = create_edgelist_binary()

H = nx.DiGraph() #The graph H is being created
H.add_edges_from(binary_edgelist) #Here the edgelist inputs the edges into H

B = nx.adjacency_matrix(H) #H is made into a np matrix.
```

And below this piece of code there are a bunch of calculation based on the dataset that is put into the variable `data`. **What I now want to do is basically make iterations where everytime the jupyter notebook file gets restarted and the output cleared, and the following filenames get put into the variable** `data`:

```
'WTW_decades/1950wtw.txt'
'WTW_decades/1960wtw.txt'
'WTW_decades/1970wtw.txt'
'WTW_decades/1980wtw.txt'
'WTW_decades/1980wtw.txt'
'WTW_decades/2000wtw.txt'
```

Thanks for the help!

P.S. for anybody interested, the data is formatted as follows:

```
USA CAN          11635.4768019
CAN USA          11214.5837810
USA CUB          2414.59680421
CUB USA          2536.43425763
USA HAI          132.913585553
HAI USA          157.281076237
USA DOM          227.060708653
... ...          ...
```

Comment: You can just keep all the input file names in a list, iterate over all the names, and save the data in some other file. There is no need to open the notebook multiple times.

Comment: I think I got it thanks!

Comment: @ShabbirKhan I figured it out, thanks! worked very well

Comment: That's great, @ThomasMcDonald!